# Congruence with a Prime-power Modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How would I go about computing: 5^11469 mod 1911?

What I know:

1911 is not prime because it is divisible by 3.
The same goes for the exponent 11469.
Since both numbers are divisible by 3, can I reduce the problem to 5^3823 mod 637?
From here, 637 is not prime as well. On the other hand, the exponent is prime.

Will I have to reduce it in a way to be able to use Fermat's Little Theorem?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Euler's theorem is a generalization : If $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then $$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ holds , where $\varphi(n)$ is the totient function. This can be slightly improved by Carmichaels theorem.

Comment: Here, you can calculate modulo $3$ , $7^2$ and $13$ and use the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I so far have only learned to use the Chinese remainder theorem when solving a polynomial mod n. What would be the next step after having the 3 equivalent mods by Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes, if you know the residues modulo $3$ , $7^2$ and $13$ , you can determine the residue modulo $1911=3\cdot 7^2\cdot 13$.

Comment: no that's division by 3 on one side and cube rooting on the other...

Comment: Note that $11469=3\times 3823$ and $3823-1=2.3.7^2.13=6\times1911$

Answer (score 1):

You would go about it, noting that:

- 1911 has 1008 numbers that don't share a factor with it
- 11469 has remainder 381 on division by 1008
- use repeated exponent rules to power up to that point

Equivalently you could note:

- it has remainder of 2 on division by 3 ( aka of form $3x+2$)
- it has remainder of 27 on division by 49 (aka of form $49y+27$)
- it has remainder of 5 on division by 13 ( aka of form $13z+5$)

Equating the three above, we can solve for forms of $x$,$y$, and $z$ ($y$ is 3 mod 13 and 2 mod 3 leading to it being 29 mod 39 for example) solving for a unique remainder on division by 1911 ( we get 1448 mod 1911)